# Issues when testing Epic with TestScheduler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, jestjs, redux-observable

I'm using an rxjs epic as a middleware for an async action in a react-redux app.

I'm trying to simulate an ajax request (through a dependency injection) and test the behavior of this epic based on the response.

This is my epic :

```
export const loginEpic = (action$, store$, { ajax }) => {         // Ajax method is injected
  return action$.ofType(LoginActions.LOGIN_PENDING).pipe(
    mergeMap(action => {
      if (action.mail.length === 0) {
        return [ loginFailure(-1) ];                              // This action is properly returned while testing
      } else {
        return ajax({ ... }).pipe(
          mergeMap(response => {
            if (response.code !== 0) {
              console.log(response.code);                         // This is logged
              return [ loginFailure(response.code) ];             // This action is expected
            } else {
              return [ loginSuccess() ];
            }
          }),
          catchError(() => {
            return [ loginFailure(-2) ];
          })
        );
      }
    })
  );
};
```

This part test if the mail adress is empty and works just fine (Or at least just as expected):

```
  it("empty mail address", () => {
    testScheduler.run(({ hot, expectObservable }) => {
      let action$ = new ActionsObservable(
        hot("a", {
          a: {
            type: LoginActions.LOGIN_PENDING,
            mail: ""
          }
        })
      );

      let output$ = loginEpic(action$, undefined, { ajax: () => ({}) });

      expectObservable(output$).toBe("a", {
        a: {
          type: LoginActions.LOGIN_FAILURE,
          code: -1
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

However, I have this second test that fails because the actual value is an empty array (There is no login failed returned):

```
  it("wrong credentials", () => {
    testScheduler.run(({ hot, cold, expectObservable }) => {
      let action$ = new ActionsObservable(
        hot("a", {
          a: {
            type: LoginActions.LOGIN_PENDING,
            mail: "foo@bar.com"
          }
        })
      );

      let dependencies = {
        ajax: () =>
          from(
            new Promise(resolve => {
              let response = {
                code: -3
              };
              resolve(response);
            })
          )
      };

      let output$ = loginEpic(action$, undefined, dependencies);

      expectObservable(output$).toBe("a", {
        a: {
          type: LoginActions.LOGIN_FAILURE,
          code: -3
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong / why this part returns an empty array (The `console.log` does actually log the code):

```
            if (response.code !== 0) {
              console.log(response.code);
              return [ loginFailure(response.code) ];
            }
```

While this part returns a populated array:

```
      if (action.mail.length === 0) {
        return [ loginFailure(-1) ];
      }
```

Comment: I'm guessing the use of Promise is causing the test to actually be asynchronous. Try changing the stub of `ajax` to use `of(response)` instead of `from`

Comment: @NickL I changed `from` to `of` and removed the Promise creation, it works as expected. Thank for your insight, if you can make a response from your comment, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the use of Promise is causing the test to actually be asynchronous. Try changing the stub of `ajax` to use `of(response)` instead of `from`